# How does this extraReducers processing work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have multiple thunk actions and I would like to process their fulfilled state differently. I have a slice with `extraReducers` like so:

```
extraReducers: {
  // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
  [getRoot.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
    state.data = action.payload;
    console.log('getRoot');
  },
  [getChildren.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
    var parent = findParent(state.data, action.parentId);
    parent.items.push(action.payload.children);
    console.log('getChildren');
  }
}
```

and thunk actions like so:

```
export const getRoot = createAsyncThunk('data/nodes/getRoot', async () => {
    console.log('getRoot invoked');
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/nodes/root');
    const data = await response.data;
    return data;
});

export const getChildren = createAsyncThunk('data/nodes/getRoot', async params => {
    console.log('getChildren invoked');
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/nodes/' + params.id + '/children');
    const data = await response.data;
    return data;
});
```

The problem I have right now is that when I call `getRoot` action, `getChildren.fulfilled` is processed instead, and I don't understand why.

This is my console ouput:

```
getRoot invoked
getChildren completed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've created two different async thunks **with the same action type string prefix**: `'data/nodes/getRoot'`.

From there, you are creating two different object keys that are the same string, effectively:

```js
extraReducers: {
  'data/nodes/getRoot/fulfilled': (state, action) => {
    state.data = action.payload;
    console.log('getRoot');
  },
  'data/nodes/getRoot/fulfilled': (state, action) => {
    var parent = findParent(state.data, action.parentId);
    parent.items.push(action.payload.children);
    console.log('getChildren');
  }
}
```

When you have the same key defined twice in an object in JS, the second definition overrides the first.

The fix is to give each of your thunks a unique action type string prefix.